# Accord.net TemplateMatch[]

Tags: c#, accord.net

Hey Iam trying to match 2 bitmaps which ConvertedTo24bpp. But its running in to a endless loop it never ends the machting process. The programm stops after 60secs.

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Imaging_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching.htm

```
TemplateMatch[] templateMatcheArray = exhaustiveTemplateMatching.ProcessImage((new ResizeBilinear(bitmapGetImage.Width / scale, bitmapGetImage.Height / scale)).Apply(bitmapGetImage),
                (new ResizeBilinear(bitmapConverted.Width / scale, bitmapConverted.Height / scale)).Apply(bitmapConverted));
```

Comment: Try searching nugget library for alternative

Comment: I imported the nuggets for Accord.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it the problem was the ResizeBilinear Class. Iam using this before I templateMatch and it works.

```
ResizeBilinear resizeBilinear = new ResizeBilinear(200, 200);
        bitmapConverted = resizeBilinear.Apply(bitmapConverted);
        bitMapTemplate = resizeBilinear.Apply(bitMapTemplate);
        //comparing our to bmp
        TemplateMatch[] templateMatcheArray = exhaustiveTemplateMatching.ProcessImage(bitmapConverted, bitMapTemplate);
```